# Como deixar imagem .svg responsiva inserida diretamente no html

Tags: css, svg

Possuo uma imagem do mapa do Brasil em `svg` todo mapeada e ao redimensionar a minha página a mesma não acompanha esse redimensionamento, já li alguns artigos e tentei algumas soluções e em nenhuma delas obtive sucesso

A página com o mapa e o código está aqui:

[Representantes](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/representantes.php)

O que tentei foi isso, retirar o tamanho definido para a mesma que é `stroke-width="1.0404"` e tentar trabalhar com o css para resolver, mas não consegui

```
.mapa {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: você vai inserir o SVG diretamente no html ou voce vai embedar? vai colocar como plano de fundo de algum elemento? ou numa tag img?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rnbr/94h9oveb/

Comment: Olá @user3632930, realmente não tinha comentado que o .svg está inserido diretamente no html, foi um erro de minha parte.

Comment: [Link que pode ser util para quem quer deixar uma imagem SVG responsiva](https://willianjusten.com.br/criando-svg-responsivo/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre uso a largura em %  quando faço leiaute responsivo, fiz o teste aqui, funcionou + ou -, não sei se ajuda:

```
    svg {
    height: auto;
    width: 100% //do elemento pai}
```

Comment: mas ele nao disse como esta fazendo isso, ele não especificou se o svg ta direto no html, com uma classe, ou se esta como background de uma div

Comment: Olá @Nilson, a ajuda foi fantástica, simples e funcional.

Answer (score 6):

**SVG embedado usando** `<img>`:

`<img src="my_SVG_file.svg" alt="Image description." />`

css:

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnLc174j/

**SVG como background de uma** `<div>`:

`<div class="mysvg"></div>`

css:

```
.mysvg {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(your_SVG.svg);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4k6rru5/

**diretamente no html:**

mais complicado, e daria um bom artigo aqui mesmo, então, porque não ler um já pronto?
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/

Comment: Olá @user3632930, realmente não tinha comentado que o .svg está inserido diretamente no html, foi um erro de minha parte, mas agradeço a dica que funcionou também.